# How do I directly add a controller in LoopBack 4?

Tags: loopbackjs

### EDIT:  This was just a bug with loopback, I've put in a PR.

The following code does not work:

```
// BAD CODE

import {ApplicationConfig} from '@loopback/core';
import {RestApplication, RestServer, get} from '@loopback/rest';


export class HelloController {
  @get('/hello')
  hello(): string {
    return 'Hello world!';
  }
}

export class HelloWorldApplication extends RestApplication {
  constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
        super(options);

        this.controller(HelloController); // Error Here
  }

  async start() {
    await super.start();
        const rest = await this.getServer(RestServer);
        console.log(
            `REST server running on localhost:${await rest.get('rest.port')}`,
        );
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: paramTypes is not iterable
>       at resolveControllerSpec (/Users/seph/Code/Project/api-loopback/node_modules/@loopback/openapi-v3/src/controller-spec.ts:312:21)

---

**How can I *directly* add a controller in LoopBack 4?**

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this helps but you can inject another controller through the constructor of current controller. You should also generate your controller  like using
lb4 controller then assuming you have 2 controllers created and want to access 1st of them inside of the second one you could do:

```
constructor(   
// Inject other controller
@inject('controllers.SomeOtherController')
// Create localy
public otherCtrl: SomeOtherController,
```

and then

```
otherCtrl.SomeMethod()
```

Read more [Loopback Controllers](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Controllers.html)

Regards,